bash - Extract proxy credentials from property
How could I extract the username and password from a properties file, test_properties.sh, shown below:
#!/bin/bash

# Various irrelevant stuff
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxy-host:port"

such that I'd end up with two variables, e.g. proxy_user=username and proxy_pw=password?
Thanks in advance.

Combining read and awk you could do something like this:
$ https_proxy="$(grep "https_proxy" test_properties.sh | cut -d'=' -f2-)"
$ read -r proxy_user proxy_password <<<$(awk -F[/@:] '{print $4 " " $5}' <<<"$https_proxy")
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" $proxy_user $proxy_password
username
password


Interestingly, this didn't work on Mac's zsh shell, even with gawk installed and set up properly and so on. A difference in read, maybe? However, it does work on the remote GNU bash 4.2 that I need it to work on, so I'm accepting it. Thank you very much!

We can use a multi-character IFS setting to split https_proxy into the desired components:
IFS='/:@' read -r _ _ _ proxy_user proxy_pw _ <<< "${https_proxy}"

Where:

IFS='/:@' - define three different delimiters - / : @ - for splitting the input
_ - dummy placeholder for a single component
_ _ _ proxy_user proxy_pw _ - save 1st three components is dummy placeholder, store next two components in variables proxy_user and proxy_pw, then store everything else in the last dummy placehold
<<< "${https_proxy}" - feed the input string via a here-string
NOTE: by using these builtin capabilities of bash we eliminate the need for spawning any (costly) subshells

Results:
$ typeset -p proxy_user proxy_pw
declare -- proxy_user="username"
declare -- proxy_pw="password"


You can lookup here how to manipulate strings in bash:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html
And by utilizing expr you can do regular expressions:
#!/bin/bash

# Various irrelevant stuff
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxy-host:port"
proxy_user=`expr $https_proxy : '.*\/\([^:]*\)'`
proxy_pw=`expr $https_proxy : '.*\:\(.*\)@'`

echo $proxy_user
echo $proxy_pw


Unless you have bash version lower than 3 BASH_REMATCH should be used which was added somewhere around 2004, then expr is not needed (obsolete some would say). , something like: regex='^.+/([^:]*):([^@]*).+$'; [[ "$https_proxy" =~ $regex ]] && proxy_user=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; proxy_password=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; declare -p proxy_{user,password}
